# ansible extra vars Hashing filters

Tags: linux, jenkins, ansible

I create a playbook that allows to change user password.
This paybook will be executed with jenkins and I would like to set the password as a parameter of the job.

tasks/main.yml

```
---
- name: "Change user password"
  user:
    name: "{{user_name}}"
    password: "{{new_password}"
    update_password: always
```

defaults/main.yml

```
user_name: "{{user}}"
password: "{{password}}"
new_password: "{{ '"{{password}}"'|password_hash('sha512') }}"
```

I think my problem is on "{{ '"{{password}}"'|password_hash('sha512') }}".

I run playbook with :

```
ansible-playbook -e "user_name=<user>" -e "password=<best_password> -e "role=<role_name>" -e "server=<list_server>" main.yml
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`password: "{{password}}"` this is recursive definition, which is not allowed. Why do you need this?

`new_password: "{{ '"{{password}}"'|password_hash('sha512') }}"` this is nested Jinja2 expression, which is not allowed. Use `new_password: "{{ password | password_hash('sha512') }}"`

Comment: I want to be able to set the password in an extra vars.

Comment: This expression `new_password: "{{ password | password_hash('sha512') }}"` refer variable `password`. If you call playbook with `-e password=mypassword`, variable `new_password` will contain hashed "mypassword" string.

Comment: i'm so noob,  ty a lot !